# How to use ViewModel for view data from two table and register two Table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

I used DatabaseFirst in asp.netMvc. and i have use multiple tables for one view and Register in database.

**1. I have user table with fix fields:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[UserType] [int] NOT NULL,
[UserName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[PassWord] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[PhoneNumber] [varchar](11) NOT NULL,
[Address] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
[ChargeAccount] [bigint] NULL,
```

userType field is ForeignKey in UserType Table that include("Admin" ,"User" ,..)
and i have another table with custome fields:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Fields](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[FieldName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[FieldTypeID] [int] NOT NULL,
[DisplayFieldName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
```

that FieldType is table that include("textbox" ,...)
now , i want to create RegisterForm with to Insert.Also i have problem to get selectedvalue for UserTypeDropDown.

**2. I wrote this ViewModel:**

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    protected UserTypeFeatch userTypeFeatch;
    public UserViewModel()
    {
        userTypeFeatch = new UserTypeFeatch();
    }
    public virtual UserType UserType1 { get; set; }
    public int UserTypeID { get; set; }
    public string UserTypeName { get; set; }

    public int SelectedUserType;
    public IEnumerable<UserType> UserTypes
    {
        get
        {
            return userTypeFeatch.GetUserType();
        }
        set {  }
    }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string PassWord { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

**And my problem is how to set CustomeFields in VM and Retrieve selected Value and register CustomeFields.**

Answer (score 0):

To get value of dropdown :

You need two more properties in your view model which you can bind to your drop down.

```
public ICollection<SelectListItem> UserTypes { get; set; }
public long UserTypeId { get; set; }
```

Add Values of dropdown in selectlist item like below :

```
var emplyee = new Employee();
var userTypeSelectList = new List<SelectListItem>();
        userTypeSelectList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "ABC", Value = "1" });
        userTypeSelectList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "XYZ", Value = "2" });
        userTypeSelectList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "PQR", Value = "3" });
emplyee.UserTypes = userTypeSelectList;
```

Include below namespace in class file:

using System.Web.Mvc;

Now in view add dropdown.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.UserTypeId, new SelectList(Model.UserTypes, "Value", "Text"), new { @class = "form-control"})
```

So now in post method you will get selected usertype Id.

Comment: `UserType` is already `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` Creating another identical one using `new SelectList(...)` in the view is pointless extra overhead . Its just `@Html.DropDownListFor(m  => m.UserTypeId, Model.UserType, new { .. })`

Answer (score 0):

In your view model include the below code.

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> UserTypesItemList = UserTypes.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.UserTypeName, Value = x.UserTypeID.ToString() });
```

and in view you have to include selected item list

`@Html.DropDownList("DropDownID", Model.UserTypesItemList, "Please select")` Hope it helps you.

Comment: it's Ok.but problem it is that when i save data to db UserDataType not set and show error!@vinutha-N

Comment: i think that i mute be write the code in conreoller.but what?!!

Comment: can you post your error message? where u are stopped.

Comment: in the `storeDb.SaveChanges();` stopped.

Comment: The problem isn't that EF is calling SaveChanges(), it is that when SaveChanges is being called no rows were updated.